# How did my textbook remove the absolute value from this linear differential equation problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value

The question is to solve the inital-value problem $xy'=y+x^2\sin{x}, y\left(\pi\right)=0$. I got to the same answer as the textbook except I have an x in absolute value. Here's what I did:
$$y'-\frac{y}{x}=x\sin{x}$$
$$y'e^{-\int{\frac{1}{x}dx}}-\frac{y}{x}e^{-\int{\frac{1}{x}dx}}=x\sin{\left(x\right)}e^{-\int{\frac{1}{x}dx}}$$
$$\frac{y'}{|x|}-\frac{y}{x|x|}=\frac{x\sin{x}}{|x|}$$
$$\frac{y}{|x|}=\int{\frac{x\sin{x}}{|x|}dx}$$
$$\frac{y}{|x|}=-\frac{x\cos{x}}{|x|}+\int{\left[\frac{x}{|x|}\right]'\cos{x}dx}+C=-\frac{x\cos{x}}{|x|}+C$$
$$y=-x\cos{x}+C|x|$$
$$y\left(\pi\right)=0=-\pi\cos{\pi}+C\pi\implies{C=-1}$$
$$y=-x\cos{x}-|x|$$
However, the textbook's answer is $y=-x\cos{x}-x$. Where did I go wrong / how did they remove it?

Comment: You can deduce
$$
\frac{y'}{x}-\frac{y}{x^2}=\frac{x\sin x}{x}=\sin x
$$
directly from the ODE by dividing this with $x\not=0$. The step where you multiply by $e^{-\int\frac{1}{x}\,dx}$ is not necessary.

Comment: Aside from that integrating factor is not necessary here as @Kurt_G already noted, after your third line, multiply both sides by $|x|$ to get rid of it

Answer (score 1):

The domain of your ODE does not contain the line $x=0$. The differential equation is either singular there, or simply not defined. As such, the integrating factor $e^c|x|^{-1}$ can be chosen to be $x^{-1}$ in both parts of the domain.

The difference to any other possible integrating factor is a constant factor. It may be a different constant for each connected part of the domain.